# self-hosted agent is not working for docker container

Tags: azure, docker, devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Problem:
We are trying to run self-hosted agent on my Windows 10 (Enterprise) machine using docker-container approach as explained in article. We can create docker image successfully (for Windows) as explained in mentioned article but while executing the created image with run command we are getting below error. We tried to google it but didn’t find any resolution.

Error:
Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent...
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote name could not be resolved: 'dev.azure.com'

Steps Followed:

1. Installed docker engine on my Windows 10 laptop
2. Followed instructions mentioned in aforementioned article and able to create docker image with docker build command.
3. But while running below command to run created docker image, we are getting above error.
4. *docker run -e AZP_URL="https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/" -e AZP_TOKEN="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -e AZP_AGENT_NAME="LocalSelfHostTest1" -e AZP_POOL="LocalSelfHostTest" dockeragent:latest*

XXXXXXXXX – PAT generated for my project.

We’ll appreciate your help.

Regards
arvind

Comment: Could be a dns issue? if you ping `dev.azure.com` from the box, does it resolve the ip address?

Comment: yes it resolves .

Comment: Hi @ArvindBhatt, Glad to hear that your problem has been solved. Could you share the solution here as the answer? Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hey looks my earlier reply was confusing. issue still persist. in earlier reply I meant if I use ping dev.azure.com then i get reply. but getting same error when I run container.

Comment: can you do the same ping from inside the container?